# Format string number as currency

Tags: javascript, regex, string-formatting, money-format

I would like a mask function to format number (as string) like a lot of mask plugins do.

Desired behavior:

```
format('1') // '0,01'
format('12') // '0,12'
format('123') // '1,23'
format('12345678') // '123.456,78'
```

It would be better if the formatter achieve this using only regex functions.

**[EDIT]**

A searched a lot of questions here in stackoverflow but mostly answers consist in add two decimal cases at the end of string. That's not what I expected.

EXPECTED:

```
format('1') // '0,01'
format('123') // '1,23'
```

NOT EXPECTED:

```
format('1') // '1,00'
format('123') // '123,00'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript

Comment: @Barmar My question is probably duplicated but the answers given in your comment doesnt work for me. The output is not the same as I mentioned

Comment: It isn't the same mask behavior so it is not 'the same idea'. I edited my question anyway.

Comment: Looks like "divided by  100"!?

Comment: @meck373 oh, works :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a two-step solution: get the digits sorted into 3+ digit numbers and 1-2 digit numbers with

```
^(?:(\d+)(\d{2})|(\d{1,2}))$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zI6bD9/2)

So, the numbers bigger than 1 will have their integer parts in Group 1 and decimal parts in Group 2, and Group 3 will hold all fractional numbers less than 0.

Then, we check the number we get and only add thousand separators to the integer parts with

```
.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.")
```

See the JS demo:

```js
function format(s) {
  var re = /^(?:(\d+)(\d{2})|(\d{1,2}))$/; 
  if ((m = s.match(re)) !== null) {   
      if (m[3]) {                     // We have 1 or 2 digit number
          return m[3].length == 1 ? 
              "0,0" + m[3] : "0," + m[3];
      } else {                       // We have a longer number
          return m[1].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1.") + "," + m[2];
      }
    
    }
}

document.body.innerHTML = format('1') + "<br/>"; // '0,01'
document.body.innerHTML += format('12') + "<br/>"; // '0,12'
document.body.innerHTML += format('123') + "<br/>"; // '1,23'
document.body.innerHTML += format('12345678') + "<br/>"; // '123.456,78'
```

Actually, you may add the thousand and decimal separators as the function arguments:

```js
function format(str, thd, dec) {
  var re = /^(?:(\d+)(\d{2})|(\d{1,2}))$/; 
  if ((m = str.match(re)) !== null) {   
    if (m[3]) {                     // We have 1 or 2 digit number
      return m[3].length == 1 ? 
         "0" + dec + "0" + m[3] : "0" + dec + m[3];
    } else {                       // We have a longer number
         return m[1].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1" + thd) + dec + m[2];
    }
  }
}

var thd = "."; // Thousand separator
var dec = ","; // Decimal separator
document.body.innerHTML = format('1', thd, dec) + "<br/>"; // '0,01'
document.body.innerHTML += format('12', thd, dec) + "<br/>"; // '0,12'
document.body.innerHTML += format('123', thd, dec) + "<br/>"; // '1,23'
document.body.innerHTML += format('12345678', thd, dec) + "<br/>"; // '123.456,78'
```